# Fabrication Gem difficult association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, fabrication-gem

I tried to use [Fabrication](https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication) gem in order to populate db in development in rails project.

The problem is I do feel that Fabrication is very powerful instrument, however except for the simple association I cannot do anything else.

For example, I have the following models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :src_reviews, :class_name => 'Review', :foreign_key => '...'
  has_many :dst_reviews, :class_name => 'Review', :foreign_key => '...'

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :src_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => '...' 
  belongs_to :dst_user,  :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => '...'
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

Not let consider different scenarious.

I do know how to implement simple association from **order** to **user**

```
Fabricator(:order) do   
  ...
  user { Fabricate(:user) }
end

Fabricator(:user) do
  ...
end
```

**Q**:However I have no idea whether I can do in opposite side.

```
Fabricator(:order) do   
  ...
end

Fabricator(:user) do
  orders {#somehow create 5 orders for each user}
end
```

And the most difficult magic is how to fabricate **Review** with **src_user** and **dst_user** such that somehow to mix them up, preferable to have user that give a lot of reviews and the same user receive a lot of reviews.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4):

The [Fabrication gem documentation](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#!defining-fabricators) for defining fabricators seems to indicate that this will work for both directions in a `belongs_to`/`has_many` relationship, and you can pass `count: n` to get n objects:

```
Fabricator(:person) do
  open_source_projects(count: 5)
  children(count: 3) { |attrs, i| Fabricate(:person, name: "Kid #{i}") }
end
```

The documentation is pretty good; I would recommend checking it out and then experimenting :)